# parentsUntil() in jQuery uses reversed order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html structure :

```
<body>
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>
        <d>
        </d>
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
</body>
```

I use the `<d>` element as the first node to start with.

Question :

```
 var s= $("d").parentsUntil("body").andSelf().map(function(){
    return this.tagName;
  }).get();
```

It should start from the bottom and to top  meaning the `s` array should look like `d,c,b,a`.

But it apparently look like : `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

Why is that ?

[**Jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/ivapox/2/edit)

Comment: What exactly is your question ? Is it about the source code implementation and how it builds this order ?

Comment: Im asking why the first element in the array is `A` where it suppose to be `d`.

Comment: I did search it in source code but could **not** find the location where it actually adds the items in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `addBack's` code (to which `andSelf` is an alias), you see this :

```
add: function( selector, context ) {
    var set = typeof selector === "string" ?
            jQuery( selector, context ) :
            jQuery.makeArray( selector && selector.nodeType ? [ selector ] : selector ),
        all = jQuery.merge( this.get(), set );

    return this.pushStack( jQuery.unique(all) );
},

addBack: function( selector ) {
    return this.add( selector == null ?
        this.prevObject : this.prevObject.filter(selector)
    );
}
```

So you see it calls `unique`.

By looking further, you see

```
jQuery.unique = Sizzle.uniqueSort;
```

and

```
Sizzle.uniqueSort = function( results ) {
    var elem,
        duplicates = [],
        i = 1,
        j = 0;

    // Unless we *know* we can detect duplicates, assume their presence
    hasDuplicate = !support.detectDuplicates;
    results.sort( sortOrder );

    if ( hasDuplicate ) {
        for ( ; (elem = results[i]); i++ ) {
            if ( elem === results[ i - 1 ] ) {
                j = duplicates.push( i );
            }
        }
        while ( j-- ) {
            results.splice( duplicates[ j ], 1 );
        }
    }

    return results;
};
```

So, `addBack` sorts the set as it ensures the added element isn't yet inside.

Answer (score 3):

`.andSelf()` causes jQuery to re-order the array.

You can try :

```
 var s= $("d").parentsUntil("body").map(function(){
    return this.tagName;
  }).get();
```

The output of this code looks like:`["C", "B","A" ]`.

Comment: Simple answer to my simple question. Thanks.

Comment: _creating a jQuery object that points to all three items in **document order**:_ you right.